# Why is my AJAX call editing the returned text in Internet Explorer?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

I have setup a script that calls my server and returns a JSON string.  The purpose of the call to return a count of the number of users logged into my chat site.  However, Somewhere between the server sending the data back and my javascript accepting the data, the data is modified.  I have narrowed this down using the following logic:

1. Chrome and Firefox both work perfectly
2. Internet Explorer does Not.
3. Developer tools with a breakpoint on each step reveals that the returned data is already incorrect at the beginning of the script.
4. Logically, I headed for my php script.  I called it directly from IE and it echo'd correct data.

Expected data:

```
{"BestOfLife":0,"Faith":0,"BookLovers":0,"Leather":0,"Debate":0,"Sheets":0,"TheRoom":0,"TheOtherRoom":0,"GayDudes":0,"Religion":0,"Brains":0,"Flames":0,"Arrow":0,"Bow":0,"Main":3}
```

Returned data:

```
{"BestOfLife":0,"Faith":0,"BookLovers":0,"Leather":0,"Debate":0,"Sheets":0,"TheRoom":0,"TheOtherRoom":0,"GayDudes":0,"Religion":0,"Brains":0,"Flames":0,"Arrow":0,"Bow":0,"Main":2}
```

Notice the last key holds a different number.  On most machines (tested around the country), this returns 2 at all times.  On mine, sometimes, it returns three.  The numbers should be changing often (based on the number of users).

Here is the javascript:

```
var userCount = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){
var userCount;  

if(window.ActiveXObject){
    try{
        userCount = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
    }catch(e){
        userCount = false;
    }
}else{
    try{
        userCount = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }catch(e){
        userCount = false;
    }
}

if(!userCount){
    console.log("Can't Show User Count");
}else{
    return userCount;   
}
}

function process(){
if(userCount.readyState==0 || userCount.readyState==4){
    serverCall = "";

    userCount.open("GET", "/src/pfcusercount.php?serverCall=" + serverCall, true);

    userCount.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;

    userCount.send(null);

}else{
    setTimeout('process()', 1000);
}
}

function handleServerResponse(){
if(userCount.readyState==4){
    if(userCount.status==200){
            xmlResponse = userCount.responseXML;
            xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
            jsonString = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;

            var roomArray = eval('(' + jsonString + ')');

            //set All the room counts

            if(roomArray['Main'] == 1){

                document.getElementById("userCount").innerHTML = '<span style="color:red">You are the only user online!</span>';

            }else{

                document.getElementById("userCount").innerHTML = '<span style="color:red">There are ' + roomArray['Main'] + ' users online!</span>';
            }

            document.getElementById("BestOfLifeC").innerHTML = '<span style="color:red">(' + roomArray['BestOfLife'] + ')</span> BestofLife'; 
            document.getElementById("FaithC").innerHTML = '<span style="color:red">(' + roomArray['Faith'] + ')</span> Faith';
            document.getElementById("BookLoversC").innerHTML = '<span style="color:red">(' + roomArray['BookLovers'] + ')</span> BookLovers';
            document.getElementById("LeatherC").innerHTML = '<span style="color:red">(' + roomArray['Leather'] + ')</span> Leather';
            document.getElementById("DebateC").innerHTML = '<span style="color:red">(' + roomArray['Debate'] + ')</span> Debate';
            document.getElementById("SheetsC").innerHTML = '<span style="color:red">(' + roomArray['Sheets'] + ')</span> Sheets';
            document.getElementById("TheRoomC").innerHTML = '<span style="color:red">(' + roomArray['TheRoom'] + ')</span> TheRoom';
            document.getElementById("TheOtherRoomC").innerHTML = '<span style="color:red">(' + roomArray['TheOtherRoom'] + ')</span> TheOtherRoom';
            document.getElementById("GayDudesC").innerHTML = '<span style="color:red">(' + roomArray['GayDudes'] + ')</span> GayDudes';
            document.getElementById("ReligionC").innerHTML = '<span style="color:red">(' + roomArray['Religion'] + ')</span> Religion';
            document.getElementById("BrainsC").innerHTML = '<span style="color:red">(' + roomArray['Brains'] + ')</span> Brains';
            document.getElementById("FlamesC").innerHTML = '<span style="color:red">(' + roomArray['Flames'] + ')</span> Flames';
            document.getElementById("ArrowC").innerHTML = '<span style="color:red">(' + roomArray['Arrow'] + ')</span> Arrow';
            document.getElementById("BowC").innerHTML = '<span style="color:red">(' + roomArray['Bow'] + ')</span> Bow';

            setTimeout('process()', 1000);

    }else{
        console.log("Unable to show user counts!");
    }
}
}
```

Here is a link to the PHP script that will echo the data for you as needed:

```
http://www.lgbts-chat.com/src/pfcusercount.php
```

Please help :)  Feel free to create a user account for testing purposes.  For now, registration does no email validation to keep it simple for debugging.  Enter a fake one if desired.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I think it's better to use a JavaScript framework (for example, jQuery, Dojo, and so on) to handle AJAX rather than writing your own code. Moreover, in the Production code you may wish not to use `eval`.

Comment: I would of course love to use JQuery.  After this incident, I am heading for some deep reading on it now lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have FINALLY figured this out.  The problem ended up being Internet Explorer's (rather annoying) tendency to cache ajax.  I noticed this when I would exit the browser, reopen the chat site, and log back in, the user count would always be total count - 1 (since it had not accounted for me [the new user] yet).  From that point out, the returned string was always the same.  My solution was to modify my call:

```
userCount.open("GET", "/src/pfcusercount.php?serverCall=" + serverCall, true);
```

Since I was only using serverCall as a placeholder in case of a future need, I added this line above it:

```
serverCall = Math.random();
```

This tricked Internet Explorer into thinking each AJAX was a completely different entity.  Moral of the story:  Death to IE.